# multiple rerendering of components in react..i am a beginner please see

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have use props as only the text and function to change it. Every time I click a number the number of times components get rerendered get twice as I have seen it while consoling. this is making my react app very slow please help. this is a calculator app. I already tried memo as a noob hoping it would help but it did not.

````
  
  useEffect(()=>{
  const f=document.getElementsByClassName("line");
  let g=[];
  for(var i=0;i<f.length;i++){
      const op=f[i].querySelectorAll("div");
      for(let j=0;j<op.length;j++){
          g.push(op[j]);
          if(op[j].innerHTML==="clear"){
              op[j].addEventListener("click",()=>{fn("")});
          }
          else if(op[j].innerHTML==="="){
              op[j].addEventListener("click",()=>{calculate(txt)});
          }
          else{
          op[j].addEventListener("click",()=>{fn(txt+op[j].innerHTML)});
          }
      }
  }
  });
 
  return (
      <div className="box" style={boxx}>
         <div id="first" className="line">
             <div id="clear">clear</div>
             <div>0</div>
             <div>/</div>
         </div>
         <div className="line">
             <div>7</div>
             <div>8</div>
             <div>9</div>
             <div>-</div>
         </div>
         <div className="line">
             <div>4</div>
             <div>5</div>
             <div>6</div>
             <div>+</div>
         </div>
         <div className="line">
              <div>1</div>
              <div>2</div>
              <div>3</div>
              <div>*</div>
         </div>
         <div className="line">
             <div>(</div>
             <div>)</div>
             <div id="equals">=</div>
         </div>
      </div>
     
  )
}
export default memo(Numbers);```
````

Comment: use blank array at the end line of `useEffect (() =>{ your function },[])`

Answer (score 0):

```
useEffect(()=>{
 const f=document.getElementsByClassName("line");
 let g=[];
 for(var i=0;i<f.length;i++){
   const op=f[i].querySelectorAll("div");
     for(let j=0;j<op.length;j++){
        g.push(op[j]);
        if(op[j].innerHTML==="clear"){
           op[j].addEventListener("click",()=>{fn("")});
        }
        else if(op[j].innerHTML==="="){
           op[j].addEventListener("click",()=>{calculate(txt)});
        }
        else{
          op[j].addEventListener("click",()=>{fn(txt+op[j].innerHTML)});
         }
      }
    }
  },[]);
```

you need to pass the `[]` blank array as the second argument of `useEffect`, so it stops the calling `useEffect` for every rerenders.

read here more about [UseEffect](https://javascript.plainenglish.io/all-about-react-hooks-useeffect-b02b7e8d7b5a)